# Disable Text Selector In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, blackberry-webworks, preventdefault

[Prevent Defaults](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-prevent-default-touch-and-mouse-events-in-the-BlackBerry/ta-p/1223685)

At the above link it describes how to prevent the default behaviour in JavaScript,but only shows you how to disable all defaults.

I only want to disable Text Selection / Context Menus

How would I go about this? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

This is nessary for the following reasons

- Disabling paste/copy on the play book
- When using auto complete the text selector pops up and is very annoying and sometimes in the way

This annoyance is caused by J Query auto select when it shows the text selection in blackberry gets in the way when trying to touch to choose one.

If came up with a work around by adding padding-top:30px; to the auto complete so its below the text selector but would like a better way to do this.

Thanks

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Tried the above code thanks to a good stack overflower ! and this solves the problem on the browser(e.g chrome) but not on the web works play book application this fully disables editing/input as well which is no good.

Comment: Why? I'm not a fan of altering or removing any default behavior, even when it feels necessary. Almost every time, it really isn't.

Comment: Explain in question , edited :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need javascript to disable text selection, CSS is enough:

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

​[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/aKkSx/1/)

**EDIT:**
To allow typing on the edit boxes while disabling text selection there, you can use this
http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/aKkSx/3/
Basically undoes the text selection on the [jQuery select() event](http://api.jquery.com/select/). Not the cleanest way, but might point you into the right direction.

Comment: Hello, good try but this code now stops be typing anythign in my input box + also removes text selector ... Thanks

Comment: Updated question please check

Answer (score 1):

Include the following line in the css file.

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: Hi, Just tried this code in my webworks application and it still shows

Comment: Did you included in the html or body tag?

Answer (score 0):

Can be handled inline, too. I think the CSS solutions are better, but I always like to know all options:

```
<element oncontextmenu="return false">
<input onselect="return false">  <!-- only <input>'s though... -->
```

To prevent selecting text I think you have to use CSS or JS (listen for drag over text) or use an image.
Note that everything the browser displays can be accessed by the user, so preventing the user from selecting text won't prevent him from removing your solution from the source code using Chrome inspect element or copy paste from the source code.

Comment: Also tried this and it doesn't work blue text selector still shown :(

Comment: on what kind of element? @LiamMcCann